# Error while creating Dynamic Select Fields in Filament

Tags: laravel-filament

I am trying to create a dynamic select field but it is given me the error "Unable to set component data. Public property [$name1] not found on component: [app.filament.pages.questions]"

Below is my codes:
       `$wizard = []; foreach (QuestionnaireType::where('active', 1)->get() as $questionnaire_type) { # code... $select = []; foreach ($questionnaire_type->questionnaire as $question){ $select[] = Select::make('name'.$question->id) ->label($question->name) ->options([ 1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3, 4 => 4, 5 => 5 ]); } $wizard[] = Wizard\Step::make($questionnaire_type->category) ->schema($select); } return [ Wizard::make($wizard), ];`